# nav links being pushed down from navigation bar when navbar is fixed for sticky navigation

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello this is my first post and I'm lost as I do not know any JavaScript.  I've created a sticky menu but the links jump down when the menu is in fixed position. Any help would be appreciated

HTML

```
     <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/asistyle.css" />
<script src=" http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header> <a href="images/A-img.png"><img src="images/A-img.png" alt="ASILogo" height="100%" /></a>
  <h2>"Quality <br> Customised <br> Accredited <br>Training"</h2>
</header>
<nav class="main-nav">
    <a href="images/asilogo.jpg"><img src="images/asilogo.jpg" alt="ASILogo" width="100%" image id="menulogo"class="imagenavpadding"/></a>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Courses</a>
    <a href="location.html">Location</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="#">Vacancies</a>
</nav>
    <div class="content">
          <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean fringilla, purus in porttitor pellentesque, erat arcu tincidunt diam, dapibus faucibus leo mauris at sapien. In porttitor vehicula sodales. Vivamus massa neque, facilisis eu felis ut, aliquet convallis nisi. Nam elementum tellus vitae gravida fermentum. Nullam et imperdiet leo. Integer ut euismod lorem, in placerat lacus. Curabitur bibendum arcu ut feugiat commodo. Suspendisse ut mi vel orci ullamcorper tincidunt. Nam vitae fringilla nibh. Nullam hendrerit blandit velit eu hendrerit.</p>
</div>
<footer>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#navwrap{
height: 120px;
width: 100%;
background: #e6e6e7;
}
.main-nav {
background: #fc6c0c;
height: 120px;
width: 100%;
z-index: 150;
position: relative;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
text-align: center;
box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
.main-nav a{
background: #fc6c0c;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
display: inline-block;
top-margin: -30%;
width: 12%;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 2% 0;
}
.main-nav a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color: #ffffff;}
.main-nav a:hover {
color: #959595;}

#menulogo{
opacity: 1;
}

a img { /* this selector removes the default blue border displayed in some browsers around an image when it is surrounded by a link */
border: none;}
.content {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
background: #e6e6e7;
padding-top: 120px;
column-count: 2;
column-gap: 40px;
}
```

JS

$(function() {

```
// grab the initial top offset of the navigation 
var sticky_navigation_offset_top = $('.main-nav').offset().top;
$("#menulogo").hide();
// our function that decides weather the navigation bar should have "fixed" css position or not.
var sticky_navigation = function(){
    var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // our current vertical position from the top
    var image=$("#menulogo");

    // if we've scrolled more than the navigation, change its position to fixed to stick to top, otherwise change it back to relative
    if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) { 
        $('.main-nav').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0, 'left':0, 'opacity':0.9, });
        image.show();

    } else {
        $('.main-nav').css({ 'position': 'relative', 'opacity':1});
        image.hide(); 
        }   
};

// run our function on load
sticky_navigation();

// and run it again every time you scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
     sticky_navigation();
});

// NOT required:
// for this demo disable all links that point to "#"
$('a[href="#"]').click(function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

that is because your `.main-nav a` are set to `inline-block`, and when the `main-nav` is `fixed`, the logo appears, and the `a` align themselves to the `bottom` by default. just add

```
.main-nav a{
vertical-align:top;
}
```

see a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V4rCR/

Comment: Thank you so much, that has fixed the links, but the image that is shown when the navbar is fixed is still pushed down, have you any ideas?

Comment: are you talking about the logo image that appears when scrolling?

Comment: yes the logo that the javascript sets to show when navbar is scrolled

Comment: what do you mean by pushed down? in the fiddle it appears just adjacent to the links when scrolled. otherwise it stays at the top of the page

Comment: also in <a href="images/asilogo.jpg"><img src="images/asilogo.jpg" alt="ASILogo" width="100%" image id="menulogo"class="imagenavpadding"/> what is that 'image' before id, i dont think it belongs here

Comment: It behaves in the same way as the links did before your fix, the main logo is in the header section but when the menu moves to the top of the page - fixed, I wanted a smaller logo to appear on the menu bar on the left hand side, if that makes sense to you. I gave the image an id so I could .show/.hide it in the JavaScript as the menu becomes fixed

Comment: i am not able to see what are you talking about in the fiddle. can you update it with any image or a simple bacground color instead of image. what size is your image?

Comment: sorry never used fiddle before, give me a minute and I'll try to upload it

Comment: the image is 1464x952 but it is in .main-nav a which is set to 12% width and the image is set to 100% width

Comment: can you replace the image with a div of fixed height and width and check if the problem is still there?